# Cant get my date converting program to print out a convertion

Tags: java

I'm a little stuck on this date converting program. I'm trying to get it to convert from a numerical mm/dd/yy format to a standard month/day/year format. Im sure its a simple fix I cant see. Any suggestion  would be appreciated.

So it should run something like this:

> Enter a date in the format mm dd yyyy: 11 20 1981
>
> The date you entered is November 20, 1981.
>
> Enter another date? (yes/no)

```
package dateconverter;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateConverter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int monthValue;
    int dayValue;
    int yearValue;
    int[] daysOfMonth = {12, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    final String[] monthNames
            = new String[]{"Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May",
                "Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

    while (true) {
        // Gets date from the user.
        System.out.print("Enter a date in the format mm dd yyyy: ");
        monthValue = console.nextInt();
        dayValue = console.nextInt();
        yearValue = console.nextInt();

        // Examine the month, day, year. 
        // Value for the month, day, year that is entered.
        // If it is not the range of the accepted value, throw an exception.  

       try { // MonthException
           if (monthValue < 1 || monthValue > 12) 
              throw new MonthException();   
        }
           catch (MonthException e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

       try { // Day Exception
           if (dayValue < 1 && dayValue > 31 )
               throw new DayException();
       }
           catch (DayException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

       try { // Year Exception
           if (yearValue <= 1000 && yearValue >= 3000)
               throw new YearException();
       }
           catch (YearException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
        try { // Leap Year
           if ((yearValue % 4 == 0) && (dayValue > 31)) 
               throw new DateException();
        }
           catch (DateException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());   
           }

        console.nextLine();  // To flush input buffer.
        System.out.print("Enter another date? (yes/no) ");
        String response = console.nextLine();
        if (!response.toUpperCase().equals("no")) {
            System.exit(0);

    }          
    }
}
private static class MonthException extends RuntimeException {

public MonthException() {
   super("Invalid month value entered, month exceeds excepted value."
           + "Please try again.");
    }
    }

private static class DateException extends RuntimeException {

public DateException() {
    super("Entered date is a leap year.");
    }
}
}

class YearException extends RuntimeException {

public YearException() {
    super("Values between 1000 and 3000 are only allowed,"
            + " Please try again.");
    }
}
 class DayException extends RuntimeException {

 public DayException() {
     super("Invalid day value entered, only accept values between 1 and 31."
             + " Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at implementing a DateFormatter (SimpleDateFormatter), along with maybe a java.util.Date or Calendar objects? Use those to easily manipulate/convert Date objects...

Comment: What sort of problem are you encountering?

Comment: it does not print out the date conversion, only the rerun program text.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you meant by "a standard month/day/year format"?

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getFormatedDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sfFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy");
    try {
        return sfFormate.format(sf.parse(date))+ "";
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

}
```

and call this function as

```
getFormatedDate("11/19/2014");
```

Mark as up if it works for you.

Comment: does MMM mean full name of month?

Comment: It's like "Jan", "Feb" the one like you were doing.

Comment: and MM means number expression of month?

Comment: @energizer Yes exactly. MMM means "Jan", MM means "01" where as mm stands for minutes.

Comment: @DavidK copy this method and past into your class. and pass your date in "MM/dd/yyyy" formate, it will return "MMM/dd/yyyy" formate of your date.